# Legend of a plot degenerates when plot pane enlarged in R

Tags: r, legend

I want to plot a legend outside of a plot area and it must be fixed in the same place starting under the x axis.  I tried

```
 par(mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 3.1, 2.1))
 plot(rnorm(100,0,1),xlab="")
 legend("bottom", xjust=0.5,"this is a scatter plot",xpd=NA,bty="n",inset = 
 c(0,-0.2))
```

However when I enlarged the  plot area and played with it the legend is broken sometimes it was inside the plot  when the width is too low and sometimes it was  too far  awy from it. Is it a problem of R studio that I am using or from anything else like margins of the plot or changing height and width of plot pane...
I have not tried it with R just only in R studio

I also tried with `par("usr")` however it was still degenerated when plot pane was enlarged.

How can I do this the legend will stay in the same place in plot pane? I edited the code. thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll need to post a MRE (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2554330) if you want help with this.

Comment: You can't.  The `legend()` function calculates position based on the current display.  If you change the size or shape of the display, it won't recalculate, it will just look wrong.

Comment: @user2554330 did I understand it correctly? legend is relocated according to the changing sizes of device width and height. Therefore, it is impossible to fix the location of the legend under x axis in the same location when the device size changes. I have to find the perfect plot by just playing with the pane???

Comment: First you should set the size of the plot to the final size, then draw the legend.  If you change the size of the plot after that, the legend won't be positioned properly.  This happens for all settings of `xpd`, but looks particularly bad when `xpd = NA`.  For other settings, the plot region adapts to the changes, and the legend is drawn relative to the plot region.

Comment: when xpd is false you said. Right? then the legend wil be plotted in inside the plot area.

Comment: No, I didn't say whether you should use `TRUE` or `FALSE`.